# Send Array of Objects including images to POST API in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I want to send array of objects ( can include images as well ) to POST API in angular and backend as Express.
This is the array of object I' having:

```
[{uid: "", image: File, description: "store", price: "800"}
 {uid: "f9b37f48-cff0-44f1-aa9f-fb9766bde90b", description: "wooden sandals", price: "100"}
 {uid: "dd5adebf-06c6-4d6c-b005-2fcb0a2ca161", description: "blanket", image: File}]
```

`image: File` here contains data as File object: `image: File {name: "s-2-small.png", lastModified: 1594528162963, lastModifiedDate: Sun Jul 12 2020 09:59:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 102844, …}`

It can contain any key value pair. I want to send this data ad it is to the backend.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose you want to send above array of object as body in post api call in angular, then you should just send the body of http as above mentioned array. httpClient.post(url, yourArray). thats it. or   May be i didn't get the question right ?

Answer (score 0):

> Try this.

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.files[0], 'image');
formData.append("Name", yourObject);
```

> send formData, hope its work for you

Comment: Yes it works but at the backedn my result will depend upon the ordering of the formdata coming.  I don't want this